# Need to use a sub element defined in another function

Tags: javascript, protractor

I tried looking for solutions but can't find one that helps my issue. I have an element locator defined in a function which was written in a js file. I want to use that locator in another js file as a child element. I tried few as below but didn't help me

```
//Page_Object.js
var digintPO = function () {
    this.catItem_status = element.all(by.xpath("//*[text()='Status']/following-sibling::p")).first();
}
module.exports = new digintPO();
```

//the another js file which calls the above locator

```
mainpage.js
var digintpo = require('./Page_Object');
this.verifyCatalog = function () {
    var catItemRow = element(by.cssContainingText("span", "Robert 4")).digintpo.catItem_status;
    catItemRow.getText().then((text) => {
        console.log(text);
    }
```

I also tried another options

option1

```
var elem = digintpo.catItem_status;
var catItemRow = element(by.cssContainingText("span", "Robert 4"))
```

option2

in this option I tried to parse the containing text to the element in the page_object file like

```
this.catItem_status =element(by.cssContainingText("span", catItem_Name)).element.all(by.xpath("//*[text()='Status']/following-sibling::p")).first();
```

and tried to call that element

```
var catItemRow = digintpo.catItem_status("Robert 4");
```

Comment: There is no input to the function and there is not return hence its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor's `ElementFinder` object has `getLocator()` method which will return you the locator used by that particular element. Look at below example.

```
var ele1 = element(by.id("username"));
var ele2 = element(ele1.getLocator()); //this will return by.id("username");
// Both ele1 and ele2 refers the same element now.
```

So in your case, you can use

```
var catItemRow = element(by.cssContainingText("span", "Robert 4")).element(digintpo.catItem_status.locator());
```

Comment: This worked and solved my issue. Thanks for the example.

Comment: To add a clarification. Protractor doesn't "save" the element, it just stores the selector as a var. When you call it again, protractor will draw the current data from that element